# Advice on *simple* (not ML) approach for categorizing text

Tags: python, text, categorization

I'm looking for advice on Python packages to help me categorize text input. No fancy machine learning at this point, just a way to create and *update* a list of phrases and assign a label to the input.

I'm a relative newbee at Python, but I realize that it's power is in the multitude of libraries that are out there - and I'm still getting familiar with the Standard Library.

Before I try to brute-force a solution, I hope that a module might exist that does what I am looking to do. All suggestions will be appreciated, since even if they don't fit the bill they will add to my knowledge.

CHEERS!

Comment: This question is too broad, you probably want to provide a few examples to narrow the scope and make it clearer . Second, when you're asking explicitly for a tool or a library you're increasing the chances that this question will get closed. What you probably want to do instead is ask about approaches to attack the problem. You should also provide an example of how you thought of solving it - even if it's brute-force.

Comment: OK... my thoughts were to create an initial dictionary with phrases and associated sentiments, read in a file with multiple lines of existing customer comments, iterate through each line of the file, iterate through  the dictionary keywords to see if they could be found in the text, append the sentiment to the comment if found or print the comment and ask for input of new phrase/sentiment if not found, then append the new keyword/value to the existing dictionary.

There must be a module in a package somewhere that already does this.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like the Natural Language Toolkit (http://www.nltk.org/) has the modules that I was looking for.

Comment: NLTK is your best friend.